# How to get a tableview footer (something that is already possible for collectionview)

Tags: swift, uitableview

When I want to access the header or footer of a collectionview, I simply get its instance:

```
guard let footer = collectionView.supplementaryView(forElementKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionFooter, at: IndexPath(item: 0, section: footerIndexPath!.section)) as? CollectionFooter else { return }
```

Now I can access views inside the footer and alter their values. How do I do that for a tableview?

I tried the following for the first section:

```
guard let footer = tableView.footerView(forSection: 0) as? TableFooter else { return }
```

and it doesn't work i.e. it doesn't get beyond the guard statement i.e. I cannot get the footer instance. I only have 1 section so 1 footer.

Below is how I declared the footer.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    guard let footer = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: footerIdentifier) as? TableFooter else { return nil }
    footer.delegate = self
    return footer
}
```

And my footer subclass:

```
class TableFooter: UITableViewHeaderFooterView {
    // initializing delegate & other variables
      override init(reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)


    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Comment: Explain the phrase "it doesn't work". What happens, exactly?

Comment: Sorry, should have been clear, it doesn't get beyond the guard statement i.e. I cannot get the footer instance. I only have 1 section so 1 footer.

Comment: Well, evidently that footer is not showing so it doesn't exist, or else it isn't a TableFooter. But since you have shown none of the code that configured the table view, and you have not said anything about the app's state when you make this call, it is impossible to help you. In general you should _not_ be doing what you said: "access views and alter their values". So perhaps this is an x-y question and your approach was just always wrong, even for collection views.

Comment: `tableView.footerView(forSection: 0)` returns an optional `UITableViewHeaderFooterView`. You try to cast it into `TableFooter`, and I guess your `TableFooter` subclasses `UITableViewCell` instead of `UITableViewHeaderFooterView`. That is why your guard doesn't go through.

Comment: @Starsky I added my headerfooter subclass and also indicated how I declared it in the viewForFooterInSection method.

Comment: But, as I said in my comment, the footer is not showing at the time you make the call, so it doesn't exist.

Comment: I only suspect that you created a `.xib` file and you didn't register it as a `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` for your tableView. Check [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614921-register)

Comment: No it's all programmatic and yes, I registered it. Otherwise, I would have received an error as soon as the tableview loaded.

Answer (score 0):

> Now I can access views inside the footer and alter their values

No, you can't. The fact that this ever *seemed* to work in your collection view was just a red herring. What you were doing in your collection view was always wrong.

If you want to change what a section footer shows, either in a collection view or a table view, do *not* reach right into the view and mess with its subviews. Instead, reach into your *data model* and change it, and *reload* the section so that the view is regenerated. This is true for cells, headers, footers, whatever.

Comment: The footer is not part of the data model. It's simply where I add an error label that I want to update. Why would it be a red herring in the case of the collectionview? I got the solution from SO so other folks are also using it albeit without issues.

Comment: I don't care where you got it. The footer needs to _be_ part of the data model. _Everything_ in the table / collection view needs to be part of the data model. You may not like my answer, but I assure you that it will solve your issue and I stand by it.